# Filtering rows and columns as per their values in R

Tags: r

I have a distance matrix which has data between all possible combinations of nodes.

```
    a   b   c
a 0.0 0.2 0.5
b 0.2 0.0 0.6
c 0.5 0.6 0.0
```

In the above example, a, b, c are the nodes and the values in the matrix indicate the corresponding distances.

Given this I want the output to be as follows :
Give all the possible nodes that have a distance less than a given threshold. For e.g., if the threshold is 0.4, I want the 

`output :
{a,c}{c,b}{b,c}{c,a}`

I was exploring assignClones functionin R, but was not able to get the expected output.

Can you please suggest alternate approaches , and when the assignClones function  can be used ?

Comment: `[b, c]` shows as 0.6, which doesn't seem to be less than 0.4 to me....

Comment: Thanks Ananda for pointing it. That was by mistake I have modified the expected output now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your expected output, you seem to be interested in selecting pairs of points with distances *greater* than 0.4 (which does not correspond to your problem description). If this is the case, you could try the following:

```
dist_pairs <- which(df1!=0 & df1 > 0.4, arr.ind=TRUE)
dist_pairs[] <- sapply(dist_pairs, function(x) x <- letters[x])
> dist_pairs
#     row col
#[1,] "c" "a"
#[2,] "c" "b"
#[3,] "a" "c"
#[4,] "b" "c"
```

Else, if you want those pairs below the threshold of 0.4, change the `>` sign to a `<` sign.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(0, 0.2, 0.5), b = c(0.2, 0, 0.6), 
c = c(0.5, 0.6, 0)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Modified the problem description

Comment: Hello @Hima ! I'm glad that my answer was helpful. Rather than the title, I was referring to the text: "Give all the possible nodes that have a distance less than a given threshold." I believe that, according to your expected output, this should be "..a distance larger than..".